# Matrix changing all values to character when taken randomly from a character vector

Tags: r, vector, character

I am trying to generate a matrix for my data generation work. The current code is given

```
nb<-sample(1:6,3,replace = T)
bt<-c("S","M","L")
df<-matrix(0,3,3)
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,1]<-nb[i]
  df[i,2]<-as.numeric(sample(bt,1,replace = T))
}
```

But the problem is it is changing all the value to character values 
If I am changing the `bt<-c(1,2,3)`it is working fine as all the values are numeric.

Can anyone help me with that? I just need column 2 to be character without affecting other column values

Comment: A `matrix` can only have one class. You can use dataframe /lists to store data of multiple classes.

Comment: How to create dataframe ? Can you help in the similar code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matrix` can hold data of only one class. We can use `data.frame` to store data of multiple classes. Also we don't need `for` loop here. You can try :

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,3,3))
df[[1]] <- nb
df[[2]] <- sample(bt, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

df
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  M  0
#2  5  M  0
#3  6  S  0

str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ V1: int  1 5 6
#$ V2: chr  "M" "M" "S"
#$ V3: num  0 0 0
```